# Iframe inside dive container , as window modal

Tags: jquery, css, iframe

I create css/jquery resize window, in css with 3 parts, title , container and footer, inside container of this window, i insert iframe, and all windows can be resized, from the corner bottom right

**The problem it´s the next:**

If footer use div in position relative, problem it´s container no expanded the same time and when resize footer can´t see or his height it´s reduced

By other side if use position absolute for footer, scrollbar from iframe hide under this div

I try all kind of combinations from CSS and i don´t find any solution for this

**I create Jsfiddle for the people can see this :**

https://jsfiddle.net/8t5a0wcf/20/

**And the code it´s the next :**

```
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable/master/src/jquery-resizable.js"t></script>

<div id="win_container_gen">

<div id="win_title"></div>

<div id="win_container">
<iframe src="http://famouspoetsandpoems.com" id="iframe"  scrolling="yes" frameborder="0"></iframe>iframe>
</div>


<div id="win_footer"></div>


</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
#win_container_gen
{
position:relative;
width:350px;
height:400px;
margin:auto;
border:4px soli #111;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 7px 4px 17px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 7px 4px 17px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 7px 4px 17px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
overflow:hidden;
}

#win_title
{
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:35px;
line-height:35px;
margin:auto;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:14px;
color:#fff;
padding-left:1%;
background-color:#111;
}

#win_container
{
display:block;
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
border:1px solid;
background-color:#eee;
overflow:auto;
}


#win_footer
{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:40px;
line-height:40px;
cursor: nwse-resize;
background-color:grey;
bottom:0px;
}

#iframe
{
display:block;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

**jQuery Resize**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("#win_container_gen").resizable
({
 handleSelector: "#win_footer"
});

});
```

Thank´s in advanced, best Regards

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

As OP pointed out, below approach doesn't cover his needs.

Altered approach: https://codepen.io/ajzk/pen/RJJZOO

---

Removing typo (`</iframe>iframe>`) from your friddle seems to fix the issue, scrollbar doesn't show up.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("#win_container_gen").resizable
({
 handleSelector: "#win_footer"
});

});
```

```css
#win_container_gen {
  position:relative;
  width:350px;
  height:400px;
  margin:auto;
  border:4px soli #111;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 4px 17px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 7px 4px 17px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 7px 4px 17px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  overflow:hidden;
}

#win_title {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:35px;
  line-height:35px;
  margin:auto;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#fff;
  padding-left:1%;
  background-color:#111;
}

#win_container {
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  border:1px solid;
  background-color:#eee;
  overflow:auto;
}


#win_footer {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  line-height:40px;
  cursor: nwse-resize;
  background-color:grey;
  bottom:0;
}

#iframe {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://rawgit.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable/master/src/jquery-resizable.js"t></script>

<div id="win_container_gen">

<div id="win_title"></div>

<div id="win_container">
<iframe src="http://famouspoetsandpoems.com/" id="iframe"  scrolling="yes" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>


<div id="win_footer"></div>


</div>


<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/NlOF03DUoWc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

llll
```

Comment: Don´t understand you say, my problem it´s with iframe inside div called win_container, because i need increase height and show all scrollbar from iframe and when use this footer in absolute position scrollbar hide under gfooter, i need increase height and don´t hide scrollbar in the end

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand your problem in the first place. Something like [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RJJZOO) does a trick for you? I used `padding` combined with `box-sizing: border-box` for `#win_container_gen` and mocked high iframe with `#win_container_inerior` with height of 1000px.